# Is there a way to mix logic and functions into Underscore.js templates

Tags: templates, backbone.js, treeview, underscore.js

For a json data as below is there any possible way to construct a treeview consisting of underscore.js templates. I don't have lightest knowledge on how to mix functions, recursions into underscore.js templating functionality. I don't have the power to produce json hierarchy from the server( it is decided by upper management).

```
[{
    name: "Home",
    url: "index.html",
    id: 1,
    parentid: 0
}, {
    name: "Company",
    url: "company.html",
    id: 2,
    parentid: 0
}, {
    name: "AboutsUs",
    url: "aboutus.html",
    id: 3,
    parentid: 2
}]
```

#### Expected View output

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="company.html">Company</a>
        <ul>  
            <li>
                <a href="aboutus.html">AboutUs</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @ggozad well the html what you thought is wrong. the `UL` will contain sub items for Company menu item. Right now it is just company->aboutus.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. Ammending asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can, 
you can use

```
<% %>
```

to write javascript code.

```
<ul>
    <% _(your_data).each(function(param) { %>

        <li><%= param.name%></li>
        <!-- more code -->
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

more here http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template

hope it helps,
Good Luck!

Comment: the question was edited by Gozzad representing incorrect html. Could you take a try now and post a answer

Comment: the way will be the same.. you can write also functions in this <% %> .. but i would prefer a rearrange of the data before you give it to the template ...